# Query to Select where timestamp between date1 and date 2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have MySQL table

```
 id     product             p_image
 1      G           images\20131030164545.jpg
 2      S           images\20131230164545.jpg
 3      V           images\20140110164545.jpg
 4      R           images\20140320164545.jpg
 5      K           images\20140526164545.jpg
 6      L           images\20150110164545.jpg
 7      SK          images\20150120164545.jpg
```

Here I need to extract products from above table where p_image timestamp between two dates (for example I need to extract from 2013/12/01 to 2014/07/30 dates)

In this query I need to extract timestamp from this string 'images\20140526164545.jpg' and convert this to date format and select values between two dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the format of the string is fixed (which it looks to be) you can use the`substr`function to extract the timestamp and then cast it to a date and filter by it. Something like this should work:

```
select * from table1
where cast(substr(p_image FROM 7 FOR 14) as date)
between '2013/12/01' and '2014/07/30'
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5f1f/6)

There might be more efficient ways to do this, but this should give you an idea to start with.

Edit: if the string can vary the something like `left(right(p_image, 18), 14)` should work.

Comment: Hi jpw, Thanks for your reply, in 'p_image' column i have some different folder names also. for example i have images_new\20140320164545.jpg

Comment: @AGR Ok, I've updated my answer with a possible solution that only assumes that the last part is always a filename with 14+4 characters.

Comment: i run below query 
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE CAST(SUBSTR(LEFT(RIGHT(p_image, 18), 14)) AS DATE) BETWEEN '2013/12/01' AND '2014/02/30'; and am getting mysql error

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS DATE) BETWEEN '2013/12/01' AND '2014/02/30' LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1

Comment: @AGR it should be `WHERE CAST(LEFT(RIGHT(p_image, 18), 14) AS DATE) `

Answer (score 1):

The dates in `p_image` are in YYYYMMDD format, so you can compare them as strings.  That is, there is no reason to convert the strings to a date data type.

Hence you can just do:

```
where substr(p_image, 8, 8) between '20131201' and '20140730'
```

If the position of the date is not fixed but always after the `/`, you can do:

```
where left(substring_index(p_image, '/', -1), 8) between '20131201' and '20140730'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will working :**

```
select * from `datetest` where substr(p_image, 8, 8) between '20131201' and '20140730'
```

**Screenshot of Phpmyadmin :**

[image]